# In MIPS assembly language, how does one round a floating point value to the nearest .01?

Tags: floating-point, mips, rounding, mips32, spim

If I had the floating point (saved in some $f register) 1684.714 how could I round that to 1684.71? If I had the floating point 1684.716, how could I round that to 1684.72?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using $f0:

```
addi $t0, $s0, 100    ; t0 = 100
mult $f0, $t0         ; LO = f0*100
mflo $f1              ; f1 = LO
round.w.s $f1, $f1    ; f1 = round(f1)
mfc1 $t1, $f1         ; t1 = f1
div $t1, $t0          ; LO = t1/100
mflo $t2              ; t2 = LO
```

$t2 has the rounded value.

Comment: You should write comments in the code to help readers understand the code better.

Comment: Wouldn't this just round it to an integer? Sorry if I am misunderstanding. I am asking how to round to the nearest hundredths place.

Comment: `mult $f0, $t0` is not a MIPS instruction.